# Using onPress to retrieve data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a error saying that `item`is undefined when I try to render it using the Text widget.

How can I retrieve the value and put it in a widget when the button is pressed?

```
class AddCashForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCashFormState createState() => _AddCashFormState();
}

class _AddCashFormState extends State<AddCashForm> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  List<String> chipList = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
  ];

  void dispose() {
    oneController.dispose();
    twoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
                print('Item selected: $item');
                return (item);
              }),
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Submit"),
            onPressed: () {

            },
          ),
         // Text(item), data should appear here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to retrieve the item? On "Submit" button pressed?

Comment: yes nn "Submit" button, I think it's a scope issue. How do I set item in the beginning?

Comment: Check Mike's answer. Make sure to check if `selectedItem == null` on button pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a field **selectedItem** which is updated when item is selected. Update state in **onPressed** method. Something like that:

```
class AddCashForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCashFormState createState() => _AddCashFormState();
}

class _AddCashFormState extends State<AddCashForm> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  String selectedItem;
  List<String> chipList = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ChoiceChipWidget(chipList, (item) {
                print('Item selected: $item');
                selectedItem = item;
                return (item);
              })
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Submit"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          // Text(item), data should appear here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Why is it that I have to assign item to selected item instead of just using item?

Comment: item is used only in the scope of selection callback (the one you passed in ChoiceChipWidget). You need to store it and use as a state. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the item to update automatically, without clicking submit, use this:

```
class _AddCashFormState extends State<AddCashForm> {
  final selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final chipList = <String>[
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
  ];

  String item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: chipList
                .map<Widget>((s) => ChoiceChip(
                      label: Text(s),
                      selected: s == item,
                      onSelected: (bool selected) {
                        setState(() {
                          item = selected ? s : null;
                        });
                      },
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
          Text(item ?? ''),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```